# With protoc, is it possible to generate C# code with sub-messages marked as nullable reference types?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, nullable, protoc

When generating code for C# with protoc, the sub-messages used in the messages defined in the proto files are not marked as nullable (the `?`, used along with the `csproj` option `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`).

I have seen that, even if they are not marked as nullable, these properties can still receive unexpected `null` objects.

I'm wondering if it is possible to ask `protoc` to declare the type of the properties exposing sub-messages as nullable.

I tried to find an option in protoc to do so but failed.

What I expect is the code generated in C# clearly exposing that the sub-messages are nullable:

```
message Main {
  Sub sub = 1;
}

message Sub {
  int id = 1;
}
```

```cs
class Main {
  Sub? Sub { get; set; }
}

class Sub {
  int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @JonasH It seems it is only for scalar types. I'm looking for the same things for messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it is possible to ask protoc to declare the type of the properties exposing sub-messages as nullable.

Not at the moment, no.

There *is* some effort on this front, but nothing has landed yet. With limited resources and a lot of work on multiple fronts, I can't give any estimates as to when we *might* be able to land it (along with nullable annotations for the Google.Protobuf library).

There are proposals you may want to look at [for protoc](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/13218) and [for the gRPC plugin](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/33878) - if you subscribe to those PRs, then even if they're not merged directly, I expect you'll see indications of any progress that does happen.